# Zend framework 2 translation using getttext in jquery

Tags: jquery, zend-framework2, gettext, xgettext

I have a web page made with ZF2 and have translated all strings of my controllers, views and fieldsets using the translate method offered by the framework in the php code.

But what about the jquery code (or javascript)?

How it translates the generated strings in the client side if I haven't the translations files?

Answer (score 0):

It depends your system of translation (PHP array, *.mo, ..)

Anyway you have to print all your translations into **a js file** using for example https://github.com/recurser/jquery-i18n

you can [find](http://www.google.fr/search?q=jquery%20i18n&biw=1680&bih=864&source=lnms&sa=X&ei=4P6TUZH0IsbHswblo4DwDA&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAA) easily some libraries.
cheers